# Two mysql select queries into one query

Tags: mysql

**user**

```
id   |  name
1    |  A
2    |  B
```

**article**

```
id   | title | descritption
1    | wx    | xyz
2    | yz    | abc
```

**article_rating**

```
article_id(article->id)  |  given_by(user->id)  |  given_rating
   1                              2                  4
   2                              1                  3
```

**saved_article**

```
article_id(article->id)  |  saved_by(user->id) 
   1                              2
```

I'm changing some buttons and icons depending on whether a user has rated/ saved an article or not. I'm using two select queries for that:

**rated or not**

```
SELECT given_rating as rating 
FROM article_rating 
WHERE  given_by=? AND article_id=?
```

**saved or not**

```
SELECT saved_by as saved 
FROM saved_article 
WHERE  saved_by=? AND article_id=?
```

So my question is how can i combine both into one mysql query efficiently??

Comment: define "efficiently" like a nice SQL query or performance or both..Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` structures also for every table..

Answer (score 0):

If the `article_id` is the same in both tables, and you are looking for the same article in both tables, then you could use an `INNER JOIN` to join the two tables, using the `article_id` column.

```
SELECT ar.given_rating as rating, sa.saved_by as saved 
FROM article_rating  ar
INNER JOIN saved_article sa
ON ar.article_id = sa.article_id
WHERE ar.given_by=? AND sa.saved_by=? AND ar.article_id=?;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q9m4b6DFRo7tE9DMNqEUhk/0)

Comment: thanks for the answer @Randi Vertongen. But one user may rate an article but may not save it. So inner join isn't the solution here, I think.

Comment: @Sharecorn then you don't want the two queries to be run everytime? You would have to add extra logic to check for that

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX(article_id, saved_by)` will make it efficient.  If that combo is unique, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Ditto for `(article_id, given_by)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them to create one dataset using some LEFT JOINS if you know there aren't going to be some values in one of the tables:

```
SET @userid = 1;
SET @aid = 2;

SELECT 
    u.id as userid, a.id AS articleid, r.given_rating, sa.saved_by
FROM 
    user AS u
LEFT JOIN
    article_rating AS r ON u.id = r.given_by 
LEFT JOIN 
    article AS a ON a.id = r.article_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    saved_article AS sa ON sa.article_id = a.id
WHERE 
    u.id = @userid AND 
    (r.article_id = @aid or sa.article_id = @aid)
```

DBFiddle Here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rb7x2DtAi76xpFBJLu5kqP/0